# How to extract noise from two similar images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, noise

I have two similar (not identical) images. One with noise and another is original without noise. I want to extract noise by difference of both images and add extracted noise to original image so that both images be identical. Original image is captured by digital camera. Noisy image is captured from Monitor (displaying original image) using webcam.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Captured using webcam pointing to monitor displaying original image]

```
import cv2

orig_image = cv2.imread("./00029_68.jpg")
cam_image = cv2.imread("/home/ankit/Captured_using_webcam.png")

cv2.imshow("Subtracted Image : cam_image - orig_image", 
cv2.subtract(cam_image, orig_image))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Code updated in post.

Comment: Seems like style transfer. Noise is the style from second image which is combined with original image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are aware of the complexity of your problem.
Your issues are:
- Different resolution of the original and the 'noisy' image
- Translational error
- Perspective distortion when taking the photo of the original

Theoretically you can find tools for image processing in cv2 that can handle those problems. When you are able to get rid of the distortions you can simply apply the code that you posted to see the noise as a result of the systematic errors of the camera, monitor and all calculations that you did.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the differences between two images, you can utilize the *Structural Similarity Index* (SSIM) which was introduced in [Image Quality Assessment: From Error Visibility to Structural Similarity](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/publications/ssim.pdf). This method is already implemented in the [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.compare_ssim) library for image processing. You can install `scikit-image` with `pip install scikit-image`.

Using the `compare_ssim()` function from scikit-image, it returns a `score` and a difference image, `diff`. The `score` represents the structual similarity index between the two input images and can fall between the range [-1,1] with values closer to one representing higher similarity. But since you're only interested in where the two images differ, the `diff` image what you're looking for. The `diff` image contains the actual image differences between the two images.

Here are the actual differences between the two images. Consider using `.png` images since they are lossless. `.jpg` images are lossy and have noise due to image compression.

[image]

Code

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import cv2

# Load images
image1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg')

# Convert images to grayscale
image1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Compute SSIM between two images
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(image1_gray, image2_gray, full=True)
# The diff image contains the actual image differences between the two images
# and is represented as a floating point data type in the range [0,1] 
# so we must convert the array to 8-bit unsigned integers in the range
# [0,255] before we can use it with OpenCV
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

cv2.imshow('diff',diff)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Note:** Your two input images are not exactly the same, they are slightly shifted so SSIM picks up the shifted pixels